# Processing Multiple AVRO (avsc files) which are in different directory and refer each other using python (fastavro)

Tags: python, avro, fastavro

I have two avsc files in different directories -

```
1.  com.company.model.AddressRecord.avsc
2.  com.company.model.Customer.avsc
```

Here is address file

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.company.model",
    "name": "AddressRecord",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "streetaddress",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "city",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "state",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "zip",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is customer file which is a parent (top level) schema

```
{
    "namespace": "com.company.model",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Customer",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "firstname",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "lastname",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "email",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "phone",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "address",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": "com.company.model.AddressRecord"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to load the files using fastavro when both files are in same directory

```
fastavro.schema.load_schema('com.company.model.Customer.avsc')
```

But it does not work when both avsc files are in different directories. What changes I need to do in the files so that fast avro can load the schema if both avsc files are in different direcotry

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `load_schema`](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema.html#fastavro._schema_py.load_schema) says that it only works for files in the same directory. It's not currently possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to process the schemas which are in different directory. May be some other library of Python and Pyspark?

Comment: I'm not sure as it's not something I've needed to do.